# How can I optimise this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are 4 tables....

1. tbl_std_working_hour
2. tbl_attendance
3. tbl_holiday
4. tbl_leave

I want to find out the employees absentee reports by this query....but it takes times when I have applied this for many employees...is there any way to simplify this query?

```
SELECT date
FROM tbl_std_working_hour
WHERE date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM tbl_attendance WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id')
AND date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM tbl_holiday)
AND date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM tbl_leave WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id')
AND total_hour <> '00:00:00'
AND date >= '$start'
AND date <= '$end'
AND emp_id = '$emp_id'
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

First, I would rewrite using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT wh.date
FROM tbl_std_working_hour wh
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_attendance a
                  WHERE a.date = wh.date AND a.emp_id = wh.emp_id
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_holiday h
                  WHERE h.date = wh.date
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_leave l
                  WHERE l.emp_id = wh.emp_id and l.date = wh.date
                 )
WHERE wh.total_hour <> '00:00:00' AND
      wh.date >= '$start' AND
      wh.date <= '$end' AND
      wh.emp_id = '$emp_id';
```

Then add the following composite (multi-column) indexes:

- `tbl_std_working_hour(emp_id, date, total_hour)`
- `tbl_attendance(emp_id, date)`
- `tbl_holiday(date)` (might already exist if `date` is the primary key or unique)
- `tbl_leave(emp_id)` (might already exist if `emp_id` is the primary key or unique)

Note that I changed the subqueries to refer to the `emp_id` in the outer query.  This makes it easier to change the `emp_id`.  In addition, your query should be using parameters for the values in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Kabir . . . "not working" is rather vague.  You should be more specific about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a better way that can work better using `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT date
FROM tbl_std_working_hour AS tswh
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT date FROM tbl_attendance ta WHERE ta.date = tswh.date AND ta.emp_id = tswh.emp_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date FROM tbl_holiday th WHERE th.date = tswh.date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date FROM tbl_leave tl WHERE tl.date = tswh.date AND tl.emp_id = tswh.emp_id)
AND total_hour <> '00:00:00'
AND date >= '$start'
AND date <= '$end'
AND emp_id = '$emp_id'
```

Comment: tbl_holiday doesn't contain emp_id.....so it gives error like
#1054 - Unknown column 'th.emp_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Updated please check.

Comment: @Suraz . . . Actually, `union all` isn't better, because it is probably going to preclude the use of indexes on the individual tables (in MySQL).